# HTTPS conflict with HTTP

Tags: node.js, express, https

HTTPS conflicts with HTTP

I make my first full-stack project on React and NODEjs and deployed it on netlify.
My backend server runs on HTTP localhost.
And here is a problem:
My app works on my Mac in Chrome but doesn't work properly on other browsers and computers.

Other computers can download index.js (display sign-up and sign-in pages) and it seems there is no problem with CORS but authentication doesn't work.

Safari logs mistakes:

[blocked] The page at https://MYAPP.netlify.appwas not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:3500/register.

Not allowed to request resource

XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://localhost:3500/register due to access control checks.

I don't understand why the app works on my MAC but
doesn't on other computers and can't find an answer on how to solve this HTTPS - HTTP conflict

I have tried to find a problem in CORS but it looks like CORS is ok. Also, I tried rewriting the server with HTPPS but it didn't work.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with Netlify, so I could be wrong, but I suspect your problem isn't directly related to Netlify.

The Safari error message indicates that your frontend is trying to talk directly to localhost.  localhost is an alias for "the computer that is making the connection attempt" under normal circumstances.  This means that when someone runs your frontend, the browser tries to talk to the backend running on the same computer that the browser is running on.

This works on your computer in Chrome because you probably have the backend running on your computer for testing.  Safari is only complaining that the frontend was loaded via HTTPS but is trying to talk to non-HTTPS servers.  It is not stating that it can't talk to the backend, it's stating that it won't even try.

If I'm right and you shut down the back end on your computer, it will start to fail on your computer as well, even on Chrome.

If this is the problem, the solution can be one of two things:  You can either run the backend somewhere where it has a domain name/ip address that everyone can connect to, or you need to run a proxy for your backend somewhere where it also meets those conditions, and has a way to pass the request on to where your full backend does run.

You need to find a way to run your backend somewhere other than your own computer or have something somewhere else proxy requests to your computer which then gets relayed to the localhost address.  How you go about that will depend on things you didn't specify in the original question.

Comment: Yes, you are right app worked on my Mac just because node.js was run on my dev localhost. I also didn't realize then netlify hosts only a frontend part. So I just need host my backend somewhere else. Thank you for the answer!